# Blank delimiter in math mode

Tags: delimiters, mathtools

I'm using `mathtools` command `\DeclarePairedDelimiters` to create parentheses that stretches vertically:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiters{\paren}{\lparen}{\rparen}
\paren*{\frac{a}{b}}_c
```

For those who don't know this command, it gives the same result as `\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)_c`, except that the spacing around parentheses is the same as in `(\frac{a}{b})^c`

Now I want to do this...

```
\[ \left.\frac{a}{b}\right|_c \]
```

...with `\DeclarePairedDelimiters`:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\rightbar}{ ??? }{\rvert}
\rightbar{\frac{a}{b}}_c
```

The problem is that I need a blank opening character, that is, a `\delimiter"4xxxyyy`. Does anyone know if this character exists? Also, where could I find a full list of the `\mathchar` codes? Google did not help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Not ideal, but here I declare two separate delimiters, one for use with the extensible case only.  Then, I use an `\@ifstar` condition to decide which one to choose:

```
\newcommand\rightbar{\@ifstar{\fullrightbar*}{\stdrightbar}}
```

More to the point of the OP's question.  The `???` should be a dot `.`; however, that version only works for the starred version of the invocation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\stdrightbar}{}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\fullrightbar}{.}{\rvert}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\rightbar{\@ifstar{\fullrightbar*}{\stdrightbar}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[\rightbar{x+2}_0\]

\[\rightbar*{\frac{ax^2}{bx + c}}_0\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So I guess that the implementation of the starred version adds `\left` and `\right` are added(plus spacing adjustment), while that of the unstarred version does not, and 
 that's why "." works with starred only... is that right?

Comment: @Taekwondavide See edit.

Comment: @Taekwondavide In answer to your question, that is my working assumption.

Comment: Actually at this point is it still useful to use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`?  It seems that the main point of that command is to automatically put left/right, so you could as well omit the star after `\fullrightbar` and define it by `\newcommand\fullrightbar[1]{\left.#1\right\rvert}` and something similar for the short bar.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I am no expert on `\DeclarePairedDelimiters`, but the OP gives the impression that the spacing is slightly different (and improved) in comparison to the `\left...\right` syntax.

Comment: Yes, it is improved. Try with `f\left(x\right)` and `f(x)`, first one adds a space between f and (x). Delimiters with `\DeclarePairedDelimiters` have the same spacing as `f(x)`

Comment: @Taekwondavide Correct.  Looking at the code, it does exactly the same as `\mleft` and `\mright` from Heiko's `mleftright` package, so you can simply use `\newcommand\fullrightbar[1]{\mleft.#1\mright\rvert}`.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will use this one. Anyway, just for curiosiry, does anyone know if a blank `\delimiter"4xxxyyy` exists?

Answer (score 6):

It would be nice if `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` were able to notice when one of the delimiters is null (represented by `.`) when no optional argument or `*` is present and print nothing.

Here's a fix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\rightbarinner}{.}{\rvert}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rightbar}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\rightbarinner*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#3\rvert}{\rightbarinner[#2]{#3}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\rightbar{x+2}_0 \\
\rightbar[\big]{x+2}_0 \\
\rightbar[\Big]{x+2}_0 \\
\rightbar[\bigg]{x+2}_0 \\
\rightbar[\Bigg]{x+2}_0 \\
\rightbar*{\frac{ax^2}{bx + c}}_0
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]